# Expressing conditional variance

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I have to prove an equality which contains the following term: $Var_{X|Y} [X]$. My problem is I don't know how to understand / express such a term. Could someone explain me what this means?

Comment: Awful notation. Might refer to $$E(X^2\mid Y)-E(X\mid Y)^2=E((X-E(X\mid Y))^2\mid Y).$$

Comment: what's the whole line of the inequality?

Comment: @user190080, I solved it after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably the variance of $X$ computed using to the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$.

Comment: Good explanation, I got it and managed to solve it. Thanks!